# Even if GridView.DataKeyNames is set, Gridview.DataKeys[] is still empty

Tags: .net, asp.net

GridView.DataKeynames stores the names of  the primary key fields for the items displayed in a GridView control.

1) Even though I’ve set DataKeyNames, GridView still doesn’t store record’s primary key value(s) in DataKey object:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selected(object sender, 
          SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
      Label2.Text = GridView2.DataKeys[0].Value.ToString();//exception
}
```

Why not?

2) I assume when DataKeyNames is set, DataKey object stores both original and new  values of a primary key ( assuming we issued an update command ) and when the update is finished, DataKey object discards the original value(s)?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is too late... But first, you are trying to get data keys right after data retrieval and not after data bind. DataKeys do not get populated until DataBind.

Second, data keys do not store new post-update values. They are copies of what was available during binding, stored in the view state, and used primarily to locate records after a post back w/o doing another bind.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a GridView that was in a asp:PlaceHolder that was set to Visible=false when the page loaded. The data binding happened for the entire page in OnLoad for !IsPostBack. When a button was clicked the PlaceHolder would be set to Visible=true. All of the data would show up but the DataKeys[] on the GridView would always be empty.

It seems like the GridView ViewState does not persist correctly when the control is not visible. My remedy is to DataBind() the GridView right before I display it.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow related answer maybe it helps someone ofter 2 years .. (2 years and 2 days exactly)
I had a **EntityDataSource** bound to a **GridView** and I wanted hide selected CommandButton in a gridview based on the Id (DataKey value)of the entity  , I did it at RowDataBound event but I got an **indexOutOfBoundException** with this code(eventhough DataKeys should have been available at RowDataBound):

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int id = (Int32)GridView.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value;//<==Here
        if (FilterList.Contains(id))
        {
            e.Row.Cells[3].Visible= false;
        }
    }          
}
```

The Workaround was to add the Id as a template field set (it to visible !) in the Grid view markup and then  check for the id in the cell value instead of the DataKeys as follows:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{

     TableCell cell =e.Row.Cells[0];
     Label s = (Label)cell.Controls[1];

     int id = Convert.ToInt32(s.Text);              
     if (FilterList.Contains(id))
     {
         //hide the Select CommandButton
         e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = false;
     }

     //Hide the id cell
     e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
}

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
    //Hide the Id header cell
    e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
}
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this issue without having to display the id field in your GridView by using the e.Row.DataItem in your RowDataBound, like so:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView drv =  e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView // Cast to correct type
        if (drv != null)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(drv["Id"]);
            if (FilterList.Contains(id))
            {
                e.Row.Cells[3].Visible= false;
            }
        }
    }          
}
```

Note that you need to case the DataItem to the correct type that was used to DataBind to your GridView. For example if you databind your GridView to a DataGrid, the DataItem should be a DataRowView, if you databind to an array of objects of type CustomObject, then you can cast your DataItem to be of type CustomObject

Comment: Note: this post was meant to follow up on the reply below

Comment: Then it sould have been a comment? Answers are not ordered by post time so you shouldn't "reply" to an answer with another answer.